# SSDT doesn't recognize changes to table to make it a partitioned table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, partitioning, sql-server-data-tools

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 with the definition in TFS (VS-2015).  The table is not partitioned.  I made the table partitioned in TFS and expected SSDT would recognize the change and create a deployment script that would change the table from non-partitioned to partitioned.  That didn't happen.

Is there a workaround other than making the table changes outside of TFS and SSDT?

Comment: What did you actually do? Tried to publish a database project and found out there are no partitioning commands? Executed a schema comparison between the database and SSDT and didn't see the partitioning commands? TFS is the version control system, the same as git. It doesn't affect how SSDT works. `I made the table partitioned in TFS` what does that mean? Did you change some source files in a database project? If you created some source files, did you *add* them to the project?

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck "Ignore object placement on partition schemes" in your deployment settings (it is set by default):
[image]